# How do I fix 'jekyll: command not found' error permanently?

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby, rvm, jekyll

I've installed Ruby, RVM, and Jekyll following [this tutorial](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) and everything works fine after following those steps.

My issue is that each time I open a new terminal window and want Jekyll to rebuild the site with `jekyll build`, I get the error `jekyll: command not found`. The temporary solution is to re-run the following two commands from the tutorial then Jekyll works:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Checking that .profile  file I noticed it says 'This file is not read by bash, if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists'. I ran the first two commands again substituting .bash_profile for .profile and this didn't seem to have any effect.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.bash_profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.bash_profile"
```

I still get the Jekyll error and my .bash_profile file exists but is completely empty.

**Is there a more permanent fix or am I stuck running the first two commands every single time I open a terminal to rebuild a site with Jekyll?**

Comment: I assume that `jekyll` add to `.profile` code, that add jekyll binaries to the `$PATH`. You should copy this part to `.bash_profile`. If you post here `.profile`, I will help you to understand it

Comment: Also in tutorial you mentioned it is suggested to add this 2 line to your `~/.bash_profile`. Just do it

Comment: just add `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in your `.bashrc`. It should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` will be called for *interactive + non-loginshell*

whereas `~/profile` will be called for *interactive + login shell*

The recommended way is putting

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in the `~/.profile` itself but in `.bash_profile` put `source "$HOME/.profile`.

And the second way way would be to add

```
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" `
```

in your `.bashrc`.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile?answertab=votes#tab-top) is why the second way is not much recommended.

[More on](https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/profile-vs-bash-profile-vs-bashrc) `.bashrc`,`.profile` and `bash_profile`.

Comment: @TomBrossman you should never source `.bashrc` inside from `.profile` as `.bashrc` itself sources `.profile`. It will create an infinite loop like situation. Anyway `Ctrl+C` will give you back the terminal prompt.

Comment: @TomBrossman Just go for the last one which is the one mostly used by most people

Answer (score 1):

You can create alias for the above three commands.

```
alias jekyllb='[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" && [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && jekyll build'
```

Hence forth, whenever you would run `jekyllb` all the three commands would be run sequentially.

Comment: Thanks, this is clever but I would prefer to fix the problem rather than have to remember this command as a workaround. I'll forget about `jelyllrb`, read the official documantation, and be right back where I started.

Comment: @TomBrossman you can use something simpler like **Tom** or even **a** instead of **jekyllb**